# Is it possible to develop Windows Phone 7 apps without a Windows machine?

Tags: c#, linux, macos, windows-phone-7, windows-7

I don't have a Windows machine, just a Mac and a Linux box. Windows it pretty expensive, and I don't want to pirate it either.

Is it possible to develop Windows Phone 7 apps in Mac OS X or Linux? Is Visual Studio required?

Comment: take a look at http://mashable.com/2010/11/07/how-to-mobile-app-development/

Comment: Windows isn't expensive, when you don't have a problem spending $500 on a smartphone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

That being said maybe it is possible to run Visual Studio for Windows Phone (which is free) on Linux via Wine but I doubt it.

You can do some Silverlight development on Linux and learn some of the XAML and C# concepts and apply them later on Windows Phone but you won't be able to write a real WP app without a Windows machine.

Comment: You would still have to deploy it somehow, which needs Zune. Whether that works all under Wine is another matter, I guess.

Comment: I think I need to buy Windows, then. The Windows 8 beta isn't supported.

Comment: Maybe at some point the guys from xda will develop a way to deploy apps from other operating systems but it will be a pain to develop without the tools. BTW make sure to check programs like Dreamspark if you are a student. Basically they will give you Windows and many more things for free. For companies there is Bizspark and Website spark but I don't think these make sense if you only want to develop for the phone.

Comment: This is unfortunate... I am just starting to look at mobile development and this is causing me to develop for another OS first (Android probably). I hope the Windows people realize this hindrance and change their policy regarding attempts to encourage the purchase of their OS

Answer (score 9):

If you want an affordable and legal copy of Windows 7 Home Premium, a system builder license is available for [$99](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004Q0T10A).

There are countless reports of this running great in virtualization software on Mac OS X and Linux.

I personally ran Windows 7 in VirtualBox on Ubuntu 10.10 and it was a great experience. Definitely a practical environment to develop Windows applications in.

Once you've got Windows 7, all the development tools you need (including the phone emulator) are free from Microsoft.

Comment: +1. Better than the accepted answer. Wine? LOL. Don't think so. Going to build software = Get the right tools. Windows on a VM is the way to go.

Comment: not to mention there are free trial VM images of Windows+VS2010 etc. such as http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=240. Gets you going for a few months at least before laying out any money.

Comment: I agree, this is a much better answer than the accepted one. If you want to develop for Windows Phone, just get Windows.

Comment: The Windows Phone 8.0 emulator won't run in VirtualBox for me, it requires hardware virtualisation itself which isn't possible through virtual machines, it seems.

Comment: Looks like Coxy's link no longer works. Right now http://modern.ie/ offers free, legal Windows VM images for download that last 90 days without activation.

Answer (score 5):

> Is Visual Studio required?

Your profile says you're 16 years old. You more than likely qualify for Microsoft's [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) program. Even homeschooled kids qualify. This means you have legal free access to Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this myself, but I think you can do this using PhoneGap and their [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) service.

However I imagine its a pretty painful debug cycle without the emulator (which I understand you need Windows for).