# Is it possible to create a Windows 7 phone app in Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, silverlight

I'm able to run c# programs in Ubuntu using the mono project.

But I'd like to know whether it's it possible to create a Windows 7 phone app in Ubuntu.

If so, what packages do I need to install?

Comment: Short answer no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463669/is-it-possible-to-develop-windows-phone-7-apps-without-a-windows-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, no.

I tried to run Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone ( http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/windows-phone-developer-tools ) via Wine before but it failed to work properly without giving me problems. On top of that, you will still need Zune to allow deployment of app.